# trying to display data from database, only getting blank page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm trying to display some data from a data base. Here's the template:

```
<ul>
{%  for post in latest_post %}
    <li>{{ post.id }} : {{ post.post_body }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Here's the subview:

```
def success(request):
    latest_post = models.Post.objects
    template = loader.get_template('success.html')
    context = {
        'lastest_post': latest_post
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

But I'm only getting a blank page. Why?

Here's the model from which I'm trying to display data:

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    post_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    post_body = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    post_pass = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    post_IM = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    post_image = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image_width = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    image_height = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    image_size = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    image_sha224 = models.CharField(max_length=28, null=True)
```

Comment: @RajaSimon: You see I got a new problem now so I thought I delete this one, which is unsolved. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `all` method of your model:

```
latest_post = models.Post.objects.all()
#                                 ^^^^^
```

If you intend to return a non-all result, then you should use `filter`.

Read more about [making queries here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#making-queries)

Comment: Django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects

Comment: and if you just want a handful do `latest_post = models.Post.objects.all()[:5]`